# python pandas split string based on length condition

Tags: python, pandas, split, strsplit

I have following challenge, where I'd like to ask for your support. Suppose you have a frame with multiple columns. Here I focus on the important column (name)

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Name":["This is a long string", "This an even longer string", "This is the
                                                                                 longest string"]})


                        Name
0       This is a long string
1  This is an even longer string
2  This is the longest string
```

The Name Column has the characteristics that it is allowed to contain a string of length maximum 10. If the rule is violated it should split the string into substrings and expand it into additional columns, which all have the same characteristics of string length 10

**Question**: How can I split the column Name in a way that the outcome should look like this

```
      Name                 Name1              Name2      Name3
   "This is a"      "long string"
   "This is an"        "even"                  "longer"    "String"
```

I tried multiple approaches, however without success.

**I'd be already happy if you could support me in splitting the Name column into substrings if a string length of 10 is reached, i.e. two columns, the first column containing the string with length lower than 10 and then the second column the remaining string, i.e.**

```
Name               Name1
"This is a"        "longer string"
"This is an"       "even longer string"
"This is"          "the longest string"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split each sentence using the built-in [`textwrap.wrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) function, feed the resulting list to a DataFrame, fill the NaNs with the empty string, and rename the columns as you wish using `DataFrame.rename`:

```
from textwrap import wrap

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["This is a long string", "This an even longer string", "This is the longest string"]})

res = (
    pd.DataFrame([wrap(text, 10) for text in df['Name']])
      .fillna('')
      .rename(columns=lambda col_idx: f'Name{col_idx + 1}')
)
```

Output:

```
>>> res

       Name1 Name2    Name3   Name4
0  This is a  long   string        
1    This an  even   longer  string
2    This is   the  longest  string
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `textwrap.wrap`, however note that it still counts spaces as characters, so `long string` would be of length 11, not 10

```
import textwrap
df.Name.apply(lambda x: textwrap.wrap(x, 10)).agg(pd.Series)
```

If you want to have two seperate columns, try:

```
new_df = df.Name.apply(lambda x: textwrap.wrap(x, 10))
df['name1'] = new_df.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['name2'] = new_df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x[1:]))
```

Comment: Naiv question: am I assuming correct that your command splits the text in chunks of size 10? 
That would mean that number of elements within the list is length of original string divided 10, correct?

Comment: "That would mean that number of elements within the list is length of original string divided 10". No, consider it like this: it works similar to usual `split()` function except it doesn't allow a chunk to have more than 10 characters. You can read more about `textwrap.wrap` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this. The regex string `r'[\w\s]{1,10}'` matches a pattern of up to 10 instances of letters, digits, underscore and whitespace.

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"Name":["This is a long string", "This is an even longer string", "This should be the longest string of this collection"]})
max_len = df['Name'].str.len().max()
cols = [f'Name{i+1}' for i in range(int(max_len/10) + 1)] #create columns names
df[cols] = df['Name'].str.findall(r'[\w\s]{1,10}').agg(pd.Series).fillna('')
df
```

**Output**:

|  | Name | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 | Name5 | Name6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | This is a long string | This is a | long strin | g |  |  |  |
| 1 | This is an even longer string | This is an | even long | er string |  |  |  |
| 2 | This should be the longest string of this coll... | This shoul | d be the l | ongest str | ing of thi | s collecti | on |

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround to place markers '#' at every 10 positions, then split them into columns using the markers

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["This is a long string", "This an even longer string", "This is the longest string in the world"]})
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: '#'.join([x[i:i+10] for i in range(0,35,10)]))
df = df['Name'].str.split('#', expand=True)
print(df)

            0           1           2          3
0  This is a   long strin           g           
1  This an ev  en longer       string           
2  This is th  e longest   string in   the world
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Name1'] = df['Name'].str.split(' ').str[:2]
df['Name2'] = df['Name'].str.split(' ').str[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This does not count spaces as part of the length, which I believe was the intention

```
s = df['Name'].str.split().explode()


(s.groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0),s.str.len().groupby(level=0).cumsum().floordiv(10)])
.agg(' '.join)
.unstack()
.rename(lambda x: 'Name{}'.format(x+1),axis=1))
```

Output:

```
Name        Name1        Name2   Name3
0       This is a  long string     NaN
1      This is an  even longer  string
2     This is the      longest  string
```